# how to use azure logic apps, function aps to read, write, delete files from an azure storage(file share or BLOB)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

We contemplate a solution where we seek to read and write files from a file share in one azure subscription (owned by one company) using a logic app/function app that runs in another azure subscription, owned by another company. The current guidance on using logic app (using connectors) for connecting to file shares (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurefile/) mentions the use of storage account keys.

We seek answers to the following questions:

1. Can a logic app running in a different azure subscription use the file share connector to connect to a file share in another subscription?
2. If yes to 1 above, is using storage account keys (belonging to a storage account in another azure subscription), the only way for the logic app to authenticate to the file share or can a SAS token be used instead? We are wary of sharing storage account keys outside of our company (hosting the file share), though the other company running the logic app is our customer only.
3. If SAS token can be used, either via a logic app connector or a function app or any other script/programmatic way (running in a different azure subscription) to connect to a file share (or even BLOB) in our azure subscription, can someone lead us to any available documentation/code snippets/guidance by some expert?

Any assistance via a quick response is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, any update of this question? Have you test?

Answer (score 0):

> Can a logic app running in a different azure subscription use the file
> share connector to connect to a file share in another subscription?

Of course you can.

> If yes to 1 above, is using storage account keys (belonging to a
> storage account in another azure subscription), the only way for the
> logic app to authenticate to the file share or can a SAS token be used
> instead? We are wary of sharing storage account keys outside of our
> company (hosting the file share), though the other company running the
> logic app is our customer only.

Storage account key is not the only way. SAS token also can be used.

Since you mentioned powershell tag, I will give the powershell reference(Other language is similar.).

[Create a context by using an SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-5.7.0#example-9--create-a-context-by-using-an-sas-token)

> If SAS token can be used, either via a logic app connector or a
> function app or any other script/programmatic way (running in a
> different azure subscription) to connect to a file share (or even
> BLOB) in our azure subscription, can someone lead us to any available
> documentation/code snippets/guidance by some expert?

Check below links:

[Get-AzStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-5.7.0)

[Set-AzStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-5.7.0)

[Remove-AzStorageBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/remove-azstorageblob?view=azps-5.7.0)

[Get-AzStorageFileContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragefilecontent?view=azps-5.7.0)

[Set-AzStorageFileContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstoragefilecontent?view=azps-5.7.0)

[Remove-AzStorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/remove-azstoragefile?view=azps-5.7.0)